# Indexing the content of my ASP.NET MVC views with Lucene.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lucene.net

I'm working on a product website which has a fair amount of text. The text isn't stored in a database or anything, it's just part of the views. I'd like to add basic search functionality to the website with Lucene.NET but I'm not really sure what the best way to go about this is.

I have experience with Lucene.NET, but only in indexing records inside a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by part of the view? But if it's just text that is output, why not use that text and add it as a document with an additional field that will allow you to redirect to the appropriate view if you pull it up in search results? Something like:

Document:
    ViewLink: Article/23
    Text: Blah blah blah...

add one for each view, then search your index?

Alternatively, your views could actually load from the Lucene Index: search for article ID = 10, grab the text out of the lucene index and put it into your view dynamically. I'm not sure if that's really the best way to go though.

Answer (score 0):

You could schedule a task to download a list of required pages using something like WebClient, then parse the text and index that with Lucene.

If you don't want to maintain a list, you could make the WebClient follow links which have a URL matching a regex (eg: certain pages within your domain name). Essentially though, you're writing a web crawler and there probably exists tools to do that already.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740529/good-net-based-open-source-web-crawler
or search for ".net web crawler"

Alternatively, look for an off the shelf solution - search for "site search".

The easiest option from an indexing standpoint is to have any relevant data stored in a database - unfortunately it sounds like that's not an option for you.